Sanity studio cannot see env variables
The problem:
I'm using NextJS and Sanity headless CMS.
I want to protect variables such as the project ID.
In my .env file I have the following
SANITY_STUDIO_DATASET=production
SANITY_STUDIO_PROJECT_ID=*********

When opening the Studio though I get the following message:
Error: Configuration must contain `projectId`

> 85 | export const sanityClient = createClient(sanityConfig);
     |                                     ^

Note: this works as it should if I use something like NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECT_ID (which we don't want to do as it exposes it)
My Sanity config:
export const sanityConfig = {
    dataset: process.env.SANITY_STUDIO_DATASET || 'production',
    projectId: process.env.SANITY_STUDIO_PROJECT_ID as string,
    apiVersion: '2022-03-07',
    useCdn: true,
};

Any ideas what's going on or something to try?

This is how I like to run Sanity Studio.
Alongside .env file I have env.js file that looks like this:
export const studioApiVersion = process.env.SANITY_STUDIO_API_VERSION
export const studioProjectID = process.env.SANITY_STUDIO_PROJECT_ID
export const studioDataset = process.env.SANITY_STUDIO_DATASET
...

When I want to use an env variable I import it:
import { studioProjectID, studioDataset } from './env'

It works locally, deployed on the Sanity Studio domain, and on Cloudflare Pages, which I like to use.

Thanks for this. As I mentioned though, process.env.SANITY_STUDIO_PROJECT_ID is undefined, where as if I use process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECT_ID it is defined.
